# How can I limit the number of pages scraped with Scrapy CrawlSpider?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to limit the number of pages scraped to 5 with below code although the website has 50 pages. I'm using Scrapy's CrawlSpider. How can I do that?

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class BooksSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "bookscraper"
    allowed_domains = ["books.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://books.toscrape.com/"]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//h3/a'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
             Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="next"]/a'), follow=True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):

        product_info = response.xpath('//table[contains(@class, "table-striped")]')

        name = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()
        upc = product_info.xpath('(./tr/td)[1]/text()').get()
        price = product_info.xpath('(./tr/td)[3]/text()').get()
        availability = product_info.xpath('(./tr/td)[6]/text()').get()

        yield {'Name': name, 'UPC': upc, 'Availability': availability, 'Price': price}
```

Answer (score -1):

- You can use CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT setting. It will be the right way
  https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.extensions.closespider
  Use this setting in project settings or you can override setting in your spider (if you using this setting only for this concrete spider)
- Also you can use `deny` param and spider will stop scan on fifth page.
  https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml

  ```
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="next"]/a', deny=('page-5',)), follow=True)
  ```
- Also you can use DEPTH_LIMIT spider setting like: `DEPTH_LIMIT=5`
  https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=DEPTH_LIMIT#depth-limit

Comment: Well I have already tried that in my spider but still it seems that the spider is only scraping the first page

Comment: @BilalAnees check my answer again